# How to write test to ensure the properites (like enable/disable/visible/selectedValue) of a windows controls are as expected?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, unit-testing, mvvm

Would choosing WPF application over Windows forms app help me write unit test for testing control's properties (like enable/disable/visible)? Or whats the better way to test, other than manual, when control properties depends on many events?

Long story: At my work, we have MDI Windows Forms application and quite often I need to make changes to that. So today while I was making changes on one of the forms, I so dearly wished if it had unit test or whatever, so that it would tell me I didn't break any existing functionality. Basically, the form has a few combo boxes and some text boxes, a binding navigator and a lots of event handling to set various properties of controls(enable/disable/visible/selected value). I accomplished what I set out to do, but am not 100%  that I didn't break any existing functionality. So I was thinking, am sure there has to be a better approach than this. Would having WPF app using MVVM be of more help in a scenario like these in terms of unit testing. Is it even possible to write unit test to check properties of UI control like whether it's enabled or not? Is there some reading I could do on this?
I would love to know how other fellow professionals tackle this kind of problem? Does everyone rely on documented feature list and manual testing like us?

Comment: Unit tests working in Winforms too

Comment: @Fabio Thanks. I am aware of that and we do have unit test for our BL, but how can I write tests to ensure UI behaviors haven't been broken, no regression bugs have been introduced?